# How to add gradient background to Switch button in React-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've got *react-native-linear-gradient* library in my project and I need to add gradient to Switch button. Should I put the switch inside the gradient component maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You can give the button a class and refer to it in the attached CSS file. In the class, add a component of "background-image" and set it to linear-gradient rgb (color you want to color you want)